# Handler exception using functional components in WebFlux test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, junit5

Hi I try to create Tests in my Spring WebFlux application, follow my configs:

```
@Configuration
public class UserRouter implements IUserRouterDoc {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> userRoute(final UserHandler handler){
        return RouterFunctions.route(findByIdPredicate(), handler::findById)
                .andRoute(updatePredicate(), handler::update)
                .andRoute(deletePredicate(), handler::delete)
                .andRoute(savePredicate(), handler::save);
    }

}
```

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserHandler {

    private final BeanValidationService beanValidationService;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserQueryService userQueryService;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    public Mono<ServerResponse> findById(final ServerRequest request){
        return getIdParam(request)
                .flatMap(userQueryService::findById)
                .map(userMapper::toResponse)
                .flatMap(response -> ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(Mono.just(response), UserSingleResponse.class));
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> save(final ServerRequest request){
        return request.bodyToMono(UserRequest.class)
                .flatMap(user -> beanValidationService.verifyConstraints(user, UserRequest.class.getSimpleName()).then(Mono.just(user)))
                .flatMap(user -> userService.save(userMapper.toDocument(user)))
                .map(userMapper::toResponse)
                .flatMap(response -> created(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/users")
                        .pathSegment("{id}")
                        .build(response.id()))
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(Mono.just(response), UserSingleResponse.class));
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> update(final ServerRequest request){
        return request.bodyToMono(UserRequest.class)
                .flatMap(user -> beanValidationService.verifyConstraints(user, UserRequest.class.getSimpleName()).thenReturn(user))
                .zipWhen(user -> getIdParam(request))
                .flatMap(tuple -> userService.update(userMapper.toDocument(tuple.getT2(), tuple.getT1())))
                .map(userMapper::toResponse)
                .flatMap(response -> ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .body(Mono.just(response), UserSingleResponse.class));
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> delete(final ServerRequest request){
        return getIdParam(request)
                .flatMap(userService::delete)
                .then(noContent().build());
    }

    private Mono<String> getIdParam(final ServerRequest request){
        return Mono.just(new UserIdParam(request.pathVariable("id")))
                .flatMap(param -> beanValidationService.verifyConstraints(param, UserIdParam.class.getSimpleName()))
                .thenReturn(request.pathVariable("id"));
    }

}
```

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiExceptionHandlerProcessor implements WebExceptionHandler {

    // classes with code to deal with each exceptions
    private final ConflictHandler conflictHandler;
    private final MethodNotAllowHandler methodNotAllowHandler;
    private final NotFoundHandler notFoundHandler;
    private final ConstraintViolationHandler constraintViolationHandler;
    private final BeanValidationHandler beanValidationHandler;
    private final ResponseStatusHandler responseStatusHandler;
    private final ReactiveCalenderHandler reactiveCalenderHandler;
    private final GenericHandler genericHandler;
    private final JsonProcessingHandler jsonProcessingHandler;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final Throwable ex) {
        return Mono.error(ex)
                .onErrorResume(ConflictException.class, e -> conflictHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(MethodNotAllowedException.class, e -> methodNotAllowHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(NotFoundException.class, e -> notFoundHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(ConstraintViolationException.class, e -> constraintViolationHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(BeanValidationException.class, e -> beanValidationHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(ResponseStatusException.class, e -> responseStatusHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(ReactiveCalendarException.class, e -> reactiveCalenderHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(Exception.class, e -> genericHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .onErrorResume(JsonProcessingException.class, e -> jsonProcessingHandler.handlerException(exchange, e))
                .then();
    }

}
```

This code worked fine when I start my application, but in tests my  ApiExceptionHandlerProcessor  is not loaded and errors is handler by spring default classes, this configuration worked if I create controllers using annotations (@RestController, etc), but not work in tests using functional componentes, follow a sample test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {UserMapperImpl.class, LocalValidatorFactoryBean.class, ApiExceptionHandlerProcessor.class,
        ConflictHandler.class, MethodNotAllowHandler.class, NotFoundHandler.class, ConstraintViolationHandler.class,
        BeanValidationHandler.class, ResponseStatusHandler.class, ReactiveCalenderHandler.class, GenericHandler.class,
        JsonProcessingHandler.class, JacksonConfigStub.class})
public class UserHandlerSaveTest  {

    @Mock
    private BeanValidationService beanValidationService;
    @Mock
    private UserService userService;
    @Mock
    private UserQueryService userQueryService;
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    @Autowired
    private SmartValidator smartValidator;

    private RequestBuilder<UserSingleResponse> userResponseRequestBuilder;
    private RequestBuilder<ProblemResponse> problemResponseRequestBuilder;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        var handler = new UserHandler(beanValidationService, userService, userQueryService, userMapper);
        var routers = new UserRouter().userRoute(handler);
        userResponseRequestBuilder = userResponseRequestBuilder(routers, "/users/");
        problemResponseRequestBuilder = problemResponseRequestBuilder(routers, "/users/");
    }

    @Test
    void saveTes(){
        var request = UserRequestFactoryBot.builder().build();
        when(beanValidationService.verifyConstraints(any(Object.class), anyString())).thenReturn(Mono.empty());
        when(userService.save(any(UserDocument.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            var document = invocation.getArgument(0, UserDocument.class);
            document = document.toBuilder()
                    .id(ObjectId.get().toString())
                    .createdAt(OffsetDateTime.now())
                    .updatedAt(OffsetDateTime.now())
                    .build();
            return Mono.just(document);
        });
        userResponseRequestBuilder.withUri(UriBuilder::build)
                .withBody(request)
                .generateRequestWithSimpleBody()
                .doPost()
                .isHttpStatusIsCreated()
                .assertBody(response ->{
                    assertThat(response).usingRecursiveComparison()
                            .ignoringFields("id", "createdAt", "updatedAt")
                            .isEqualTo(request);
                });
        verify(beanValidationService).verifyConstraints(any(Object.class), anyString());
        verify(userService).save(any(UserDocument.class));
    }

    @Test
    void whenRequestHasInvalidDataThenThrowError(){
        var request = UserRequestFactoryBot.builder().withLargeEmail().build();
        var bindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(request, UserRequest.class.getSimpleName());
        smartValidator.validate(request, bindingResult);
        when(beanValidationService.verifyConstraints(any(Object.class), anyString()))
                .thenReturn(Mono.error(new BeanValidationException(null)));
        problemResponseRequestBuilder.withUri(UriBuilder::build)
                .withBody(request)
                .generateRequestWithSimpleBody()
                .doPost()
                .isHttpStatusIsBadRequest();
        verify(beanValidationService).verifyConstraints(any(Object.class), anyString());
        verify(userService, times(0)).save(any(UserDocument.class));
    }

}
```

when I run my test my ApiExceptionHandlerProcessor not loaded and a spring class org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange handler my error.

Remeber If I use this exception handler works fine using @RestController (tests and start application) but functional componentes don`t work in tests, but if I start my application a class ApiExceptionHandlerProcessor handler fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my problem, in setup method I configure my webTestClient with my functional components ( my routes)

```
    void setup(){
        var handler = new UserHandler(beanValidationService, userService, userQueryService, userMapper);
        var routers = new UserRouter().userRoute(handler);
        userResponseRequestBuilder = userResponseRequestBuilder(routers, "/users/");
        problemResponseRequestBuilder = problemResponseRequestBuilder(routers, "/users/");
    }
```

I replace this configurarion for this

```
    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        userResponseRequestBuilder = userResponseRequestBuilder(applicationContext, "/users/");
        problemResponseRequestBuilder = problemResponseRequestBuilder(applicationContext, "/users/");
    }
```

I inject in my test a ApplicationContext biuld with dependencies setted on @ContextConfiguration, now my tests using. my custom class

[EDITED]

To explain more about my solution, my userResponseRequestBuilder and problemResponseRequestBuilder are utilities methods to make requests, follow more details about the code to explain more about solution:

RequestBuilderInstances.java

```
/// new code
    public static RequestBuilder<UserSingleResponse> userResponseRequestBuilder(final ApplicationContext applicationContext, final String baseUri){
        return new RequestBuilder<>(applicationContext, baseUri, UserSingleResponse.class);
    }

    public static RequestBuilder<ProblemResponse> problemResponseRequestBuilder(final ApplicationContext applicationContext, final String baseUri){
        return new RequestBuilder<>(applicationContext, baseUri, ProblemResponse.class);
    }
/// old code

    public static RequestBuilder<UserSingleResponse> userResponseRequestBuilder(RouterFunction<?> routerFunction, final String baseUri){
        return new RequestBuilder<>(routerFunction, baseUri, UserSingleResponse.class);
    }

    public static RequestBuilder<ProblemResponse> problemResponseRequestBuilder(RouterFunction<?> routerFunction, final String baseUri){
        return new RequestBuilder<>(routerFunction, baseUri, ProblemResponse.class);
    }
```

RequestBuilder.java

```
/// new code
    public RequestBuilder(final ApplicationContext applicationContext, final String baseUri, final Class<B> responseClass){
        this.responseClass = responseClass;
        webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToApplicationContext(applicationContext)
                .configureClient()
                .baseUrl(baseUri)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofDays(1))
                .build();
    }

/// old code
    public RequestBuilder(final RouterFunction<?> routerFunction, final String baseUri, final Class<B> responseClass){
        this.responseClass = responseClass;
        webTestClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToRouterFunction(routerFunction)
                .configureClient()
                .baseUrl(baseUri)
                .responseTimeout(Duration.ofDays(1))
                .build();
    }
```

to fix my problem I create my WebTestClient instance using applicationContext, for more details follow a commit with my fix:

https://github.com/juniorjrjl/reactive-calendar/tree/4ccd3541b16b8486ecbf06db7e5af7252fb85266